# Terminology for commutative ring whose Jacobson radical $J$ is nilpotent with semisimple quotient $R/J$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Is there a name for the following property of a commutative ring $R$:

its Jacobson radical $J$ is nilpotent, and $R/J$ is semi-simple?

(It is easily equivalent to: $R$ is a finite product of commutative local rings with nilpotent radical.)

Comment: $R/J$ is not always semisimple? $J$ is the intersection of all maximal ideals of $R$, so $J(R/J)=0$, right?

Comment: @MarkSapir People usually call rings semisimple when they are Jacobson semisimple (no Jacobson radical) *and* Artinian (well, or they prove it...).

Comment: Indeed, for me semisimple means that $R$ is a semisimple $R$-module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word for a ring $R$ whose Jacobson radical $J$ is nilpotent and such that $R/J$ is semisimple is **semiprimary**.  I don’t know if there is a more special word for the commutative case.

Comment: Thank you! An aside question: if we assume that $R/J$ is semi-simple and that $J$ is only a nilideal (every element is nilpotent), is there a name?

Comment: @AurélienDjament No, I’m not aware of a term in that exact situation. It is venturing close to semiperfect (R/J semisimple and lift/rad) and strongly $\pi$ regular (R/J Is von Neumann regular and J is nil.)

Comment: Sorry I should have qualified that characterization of strong pi regularity as a commutative one.